# Leetcode 1423: How to optimize brute-force recursive approach?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

I came across [this question](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-points-you-can-obtain-from-cards/) on Leetcode. The question description is as follows

> There are several cards arranged in a row, and each card has an
>   associated number of points The points are given in the integer array
>   cardPoints.
>
> In one step, you can take one card from the beginning or from the end
>   of the row. You have to take exactly k cards.
>
> Your score is the sum of the points of the cards you have taken.
>
> Given the integer array cardPoints and the integer k, return the
>   maximum score you can obtain.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: cardPoints = [1,2,3,4,5,6,1], k = 3 Output: 12 Explanation:
>   After the first step, your score will always be 1. However, choosing
>   the rightmost card first will maximize your total score. The optimal
>   strategy is to take the three cards on the right, giving a final score
>   of 1 + 6 + 5 = 12. Example 2:
>
> Input: cardPoints = [2,2,2], k = 2 Output: 4 Explanation: Regardless
>   of which two cards you take, your score will always be 4. Example 3:
>
> Input: cardPoints = [9,7,7,9,7,7,9], k = 7 Output: 55 Explanation: You
>   have to take all the cards. Your score is the sum of points of all
>   cards. Example 4:
>
> Input: cardPoints = [1,1000,1], k = 1 Output: 1 Explanation: You
>   cannot take the card in the middle. Your best score is 1.  Example 5:
>
> Input: cardPoints = [1,79,80,1,1,1,200,1], k = 3 Output: 202
>
> Constraints:
>
> 1 <= cardPoints.length <= 10^5
>   1 <= cardPoints[i] <= 10^4
>   1 <= k <= cardPoints.length

After looking at the discussion forums, I realized that this could be converted into a sliding window problem where we have to find the `smallest subarray sum of length len(cardPoints) - k`. 
While I do understand this, 
The initial method I tried was brute-force recursive and used Dynamic Programming (memoization) to cache intermediate results. Despite this, it still results in a timeout. Is there any other optimization I can make to make my code run faster using this approach?

```
class Solution {
public:
    int maxScoreUtil(int left, int right,vector<int>& cardPoints, int k,vector<vector<int>>& dp){
        if(k == 0 || left == cardPoints.size() || right < 0)
            return 0;

        if(dp[left][right] != -1)
            return dp[left][right];

        int val_1 = maxScoreUtil(left+1,right,cardPoints,k-1,dp) + cardPoints[left];
        int val_2 = maxScoreUtil(left,right-1,cardPoints,k-1,dp) + cardPoints[right];

        return dp[left][right] = max(val_1,val_2);
    }

    int maxScore(vector<int>& cardPoints, int k) {
        int n = cardPoints.size();
        vector<vector<int>> dp(n+1, vector<int>(n+1, -1));
        return maxScoreUtil(0,n-1,cardPoints,k,dp);
    }
};I
```

Before using DP => 16/40 test cases passed followed by TLE

After using DP => 31/40 test cases passed followed by TLE

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you closely look, it can be solved by sliding window. 
What are possible cases of selection after completion of Kth pick up if we forget the order we picked up?

```
The possible combinations will be:
0.  0 card picked up from rightmost, K cards picked up from leftmost
1.  1 card picked up from rightmost, K-1 cards picked up from leftmost
2.  2 cards picked up from rightmost, K-2 cards picked up from leftmost
3.  3 cards picked up from rightmost, K-3 cards picked up from leftmost
…………………………………………………………………………………….
k.   K cards picked up from rightmost, 0 card picked up from leftmost
```

so you can calculate prefix sum and find out all above K+1 combinations in O(1) time.
total time complexity would be O(k) for this and prefix sum computing in O(n). Since N>=k so, time complexity O(n)